# Evaluate a triple integral over an ellipsoid.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate $$\iiint_{T} \sqrt{(1-9z^2)(1-4y^2-9z^2)}\, dx\,dy\,dz,$$
>
> where $T$ is the domain $$x^2+4y^2+9z^2\le1.$$

I'm not sure of my result. Can you write a solution step-by-step please?

Thanks in advance

---

Here are my steps:
I think the integral may be composed by the following integrals:
$$\int_{-1/3}^{1/3}\, dz \iint_{D} \sqrt{(1-9z^2)(1-4y^2-9z^2)}\, dx\,dy$$
where $D$ is the domain:$$\frac{x^2}{1-9z^2}+\frac{y^2}{\frac{1}{4}(1-9z^2)}\le1$$

Is this correct?

Comment: You can show us your steps too!

Comment: Yes, please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: You can't factor the dz right out,because z is contained in the other integrand.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: $x=6r\cos u, y=3r\sin u\cos v, z=2r\sin u\sin v$.

Step 2: compute the Jacobian.

Step 3: express the domain in the transformed coordinates.

Step 4: integrate.

Comment: I think it may be so laborious...

Comment: Probably ten times less laborious than your direct attack. Be inspired by this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Further_examples

Comment: So how does the domain change?

Comment: Perform the change of variables, it is straightforward.

Comment: you're right...I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\mrm{T} \equiv
> \braces{\pars{x,y,z} \mid x^{2} + 4y^{2} + 9z^{2} \leq 1}}$.

\begin{align}
&\iiint_{\mrm{T}}\root{\pars{1 - 9z^{2}}\pars{1 - 4y^{2} - 9z^{2}}}
\,\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z
\\[5mm]
& \stackrel{2y\ \mapsto\ y\,,\ 3z\ \mapsto\ z}{=}\,\,\,
\iiint_{x^{2}\ +\ y^{2}\ +\ z^{2}\ \leq\ 1}
\root{\pars{1 - z^{2}}\pars{1 - y^{2} - z^{2}}}
\,\dd x\,{\dd y \over 2}\,{\dd z \over 3}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 6}\iiint_{z^{2}\ +\ x^{2}\ +\ y^{2}\ \leq\ 1}
\root{\pars{1 - y^{2}}\pars{1 - x^{2} - y^{2}}}
\,\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 6}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}
\root{\bracks{1 - r^{2}\sin^{2}\pars{\theta}\sin^{2}\pars{\phi}}
\bracks{1 - r^{2}\sin^{2}\pars{\theta}}}
r^{2}\sin\pars{\theta}\,\dd r\,\dd\theta\,\dd\phi
\\[1cm] = &\
{1 \over 6}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}
\root{\bracks{1 - r^{2}\sin^{2}\pars{\phi} + r^{2}\cos^{2}\pars{\theta}\sin^{2}\pars{\phi}}
\bracks{1 - r^{2} + r^{2}\cos^{2}\pars{\theta}}}\times
\\[5mm] &\
r^{2}\sin\pars{\theta}\,\dd r\,\dd\theta\,\dd\phi
\\[1cm] = &\
{1 \over 6}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}
\root{\bracks{1 - r^{2}\sin^{2}\pars{\phi} + r^{2}t^{2}\sin^{2}\pars{\phi}}
\bracks{1 - r^{2} + r^{2}t^{2}}}r^{2}\,\dd r\,\dd t\,\dd\phi
\end{align}

> Can you take it from here ?. I guess some *Elliptic Functions* will be involved.